# jQuery images crossfade with burn highlights

Tags: jquery, transition, effects, jquery-effects, cross-fade

It is possible to achieve in jQuery an image crossfade transition using a **burn highlight** effect?

This is done in video editing software by burning highlights (this is different to simply turning to white) in image A until it becomes white, and vice-versa for image B.

Comment: [There's a jQuery plugin that does colour blending](http://codewelt.com/blendmode), but it seems like it'll take a bit of work to get it working with animations.

Comment: Yes, but only in Chrome and Safari. Research webkit filters and use them in conjunction with your fading.

Comment: Any example on how to use webkit filters to achieve the effect on animations?